# Spring.boot: binding request parameter to data object with nested Optional

Tags: spring-boot, data-binding, option-type, spring-restcontroller

Working with a vanilla `@RestController` in Spring.Boot, how can you use the default databinding and properly bind to nested `Optional` attributes in a data object?

In terms of code, this is the data class (using lombok to reduce the boilerplate)

```
@Data
public class SomeData {
   Optional<String> name;
}
```

which is used as a request parameter in a GET route, like this

```
@GetMapping("/something")
public void getSomething(SomeData data) {
  ...
}
```

The problem: if no corresponding parameter is given in the request, then `data.name` is `null` instead of `Optional.empty`.

What I found so far:
* `Optional` is handled properly when you just use it directly, like `getSomething(Optional<String> name)`
* Additional annotations like `@RequestParam` or `@Valid` don't affect this behavior

Comment: The default data binding processes only the properties having a corresponding parameter in the request. Would setting a default value for `name` property (e.g. `Optional<String> name = Optional.empty();`) be an option?

Comment: Yes, that works although a general solution would be nicer as to not having to remember that these fields need initialized values.

Comment: The use of [WebDataBinder#setFieldMarkerPrefix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html#setFieldMarkerPrefix-java.lang.String-) could be a general solution to use the default data binding and have default values for fields without initialise them nor send corresponding parameters with the request. This approach might still be different than what you are looking for as it uses a parameter with the name prefixed with `_`